All code and no play makes 31415 a dull boy
In this crossword puzzle by Jack Lance, all the letters have been replaced by a fixed text string: All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Therefore, you have to rely on clues like digits, capitalisation, special characters and the number of letters in each word to solve it.
In this code challenge, you have to input a string containing only the 95 ASCII printables, and output the string, obfuscated like in the challenge.
Letters should be replaced by each of the characters in All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy, in order, wrapping if needed, retaining capitalisation. Other characters (including spaces) are left as is.
Examples:
enter code here → allwo rkan dnop
Hello, World! → Allwo, Rkand!
This is PPCG. → Allw or KAND.
sample@em.ail → allwor@ka.ndn
wEIrD CaPS → aLLwO RkAN
7 days a week → 7 allw o rkan
sin(30 deg)=1/2 → all(30 wor)=1/2
0x12A64F54 → 0a12L64L54
2+3=5 → 2+3=5
|_3375|>34|< → |_3375|>34|<
&/^;" → &/^;"

An empty input produces an empty output.
This is code-golf, so fewest bytes wins!
Or, should I say: allw or kand-nopl, ay makesj ackad ullb!

Why is sin 30 becoming 60?

Vyxal, 32 bytes
fǍT≬L`λæƛ¢an∩„∨¯»¦¢₴a∩‛l½ė`Ẏ¢∑?•

Try it Online!
f               # Convert to a list of chars
  T             # And find the indices where
 Ǎ              # Removing non-letters yields a truthy string i.e. char is letter
   ≬-------¢    # Apply the following to the values at those indices, together:
          Ẏ     # Take the first
    L           # (length of values) characters, wrapping as necessary, of
     `...`      # compressed string "allworkandnoplaymakesjackadullboy"
            ∑   # Concatenate
             ?• # And transfer the case of the input.


Retina, 72 bytes
T`l`\o
[A-Z]
Ao
Y`o`a\l\l\workan\dn-p\laymakesjacka\du\l\lboy
T`Al`_L`A.

Try it online! Link includes test cases. Explanation:
T`l`\o

Change all lowercase letters to os. o has to be quoted because it's magic and I don't want it to be magic here. (l is also magic but that's deliberate.)
[A-Z]
Ao

Change all uppercase letters to Aos.
Y`o`a\l\l\workan\dn-p\laymakesjacka\du\l\lboy

Cyclically transliterate as to the given phrase. d, l, o, p and w are normally magic and have to be quoted, but fortunately I get to use n-p in place of no\p, and o isn't magic when it appears on both sides.
T`Al`_L`A.

Capitalise letters following As, deleting those As.

Is every letter magic or for what reason you need to use a magic there?

@l4m2 Do you mean the o in the first transliteration? Quoting it there allows me to avoid quoting it in the cyclic transliteration, because it now appears on both sides.

05AB1E, 35 bytes
εDai’€Ÿ‚Ÿ€ƒ€¸†•ŠŽ—Éadullíå’¾è¼s.uiu

Output as a list of characters.
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
ε             # Map over each character of the (implicit) input:
 D            #  Duplicate the current character
  ai          #  Pop the copy, and if it's a letter:
    ’€Ÿ‚Ÿ€ƒ€¸†•ŠŽ—Éadullíå’
              #   Push dictionary string "allworkandnoplaymakesjackadullboy"
      ¾è      #   Get the 0-based `¾`'th character from this string (starts at 0)
        ¼     #   Then increase `¾` by 1 for the next iteration
        s     #   Swap so the current letter is at the top again
         .ui  #   Pop, and if it's uppercase:
            u #    Uppercase the indexed letter as well
              #   (implicit else: leave it lowercase)
              #  (implicit else: use the current duplicated character instead)
              # (after which the resulting character-list is output implicitly)

See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section How to use the dictionary?) to understand why ’€Ÿ‚Ÿ€ƒ€¸†•ŠŽ—Éadullíå’ is "allworkandnoplaymakesjackadullboy" (although a compressed string .•1Á› Aƶ5~]ô/;ÖYµ¯?*mò• is apparently the exact same length in this case: try it online.)

Perl 5 -p, 67 bytes
s,\pL,($&&$")|(ALLWORKANDNOPLAYMAKESJACKADULLBOY=~/./g)[$i++%33],ge

Try it online!

C (clang), 91 89 bytes
i;f(*s){for(i=0;*s++=isalpha(*s)?"ALLWORKANDNOPLAYMAKESJACKADULLBOY"[i++%33]|*s&32:*s;);}

Try it online!

-2 bytes thanks to WeirdGlyphs


It may be possible to do it with 89 bytes, since the assignment will be executed last.

@WeirdGlyphs cool, thank you!

Jelly, 42 bytes
nŒsÄị“ṢhqQẋøḤ×HßżṘĊo6.Ṿ§@Þƒ»a@Ʋo⁸Œu⁸=ŒuT¤¦

A monadic Link that accepts the clue as a list of characters and yields the encrypted clue as a list of characters.
Try it online!
How?
nŒsÄị“...»a@Ʋo⁸Œu⁸=ŒuT¤¦ - Link: list of characters, Clue
 Œs                      - swap case {Clue}
n                        - {Clue} not equal {that} (vectorises) -> isLetterVector
            Ʋ            - last four links as a monad - f(isLetterVector):
   Ä                     -   cumulative sums
     “...»               -   "allworkandnoplaymakesjackadullboy"
    ị                    -   {CumSums} index into {that} (modular) (vectorises)
          a@             -   {isLetterVector} logical AND {that} (vectorises)
             o⁸          - logical OR {Clue} (vectorises)
                       ¦ - sparse application...
                      ¤  - ...to indices: nilad followed by links as a nilad:
                 ⁸       -                  Clue
                   Œu    -                  {Clue} to uppercase
                  =      -                  equal? (vectorises)
                     T   -                  truthy indices
               Œu        - ...apply: uppercase


JavaScript (Node.js), 98 bytes
-2 thanks to @l4m2
Expects and returns a string.
s=>(B=Buffer)(s).map(c=>(c-65&95)<26?B("ALLWORKANDNOPLAYMAKESJACKADULLBOY")[i++%33]|c&32:c,i=0)+""

Try it online!

JavaScript (Node.js), 88 bytes
Expects and returns a buffer.
a=>a.map(c=>(c-65&95)<26?Buffer("ALLWORKANDNOPLAYMAKESJACKADULLBOY")[i++%33]|c&32:c,i=0)

Try it online!

88

Japt v2.0a0, 40 bytes
r\l@T°g`a¥wŽk„dnoplayµkƒjàÚÍé¾y`c^H*Xè\A

Try it or run all test cases
r\l@T°g`...`c^H*Xè\A     :Implicit input of string
r                        :Replace
 \l                      :RegEx /[a-z]/gi
   @                     :Pass each match X through the following function
    T°                   :  Postfix increment T (initially 0)
      g                  :  0-based index into
       `...`             :    Compressed string "allworkandnoplaymakesjackadullboy"
            c            :    Map charcodes
             ^           :      Bitwise XOR with
              H          :      32
               *         :      Multiplied by
                Xè       :      Count the occurrences in X of
                  \A     :      RegEx /[A-Z]/


APL+WIN, 107 bytes
Prompts for string.
⎕av[(48×j)+(v×i=0)+i←i\(+/i←((v>17)^v<44)∨j←(v>65)^(v←⎕av⍳⎕)<92)⍴s←⎕av⍳'allworkandnoplaymakesjackadullboy']

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

Uiua, 49 bytes (SBCS)
⍜⊏(×↯:"ALLWORKANDNOPLAYMAKESJACKADULLBOY"△.±)⊚⌵±.

Pad

Setanta, 189 bytes
gniomh(s){t:=""j:=0le i idir(0,fad@s){i=s[i]ma'@'<i&i<'[' t+="ALLWORKANDNOPLAYMAKESJACKADULLBOY"[j]no ma'`'<i&i<'{' t+="allworkandnoplaymakesjackadullboy"[j]no{j-=1t+=i}j=(j+1)%33}toradh t}

try-setanta.ie link

Charcoal, 46 bytes
⭆Ｓ⎇№α↥ι⭆§”&⌊⊟“⬤Ｔ>τïL⦄⁻!ζPA;>εü⌈≔”Ｌ⊞Ｏυω⎇№αι↥λλι

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
 Ｓ                          Input string
⭆                           Map over characters and join
    α                       Predefined variable uppercase alphabet
   №                        Contains
      ι                     Current character
     ↥                      Uppercased
  ⎇                         If true then
         ”...”              1-indexed phrase
        §                   Indexed by
                  ω         Empty string
               ⊞Ｏ           Pushed to
                 υ          Predefined variable empty list
              Ｌ             Take the length
       ⭆                    Map over character
                     α      Predefined variable uppercase alphabet
                    №       Contains
                      ι     Outer character
                   ⎇        If true then
                        λ   Inner character
                       ↥    Uppercased
                         λ  Otherwise inner character
                          ι Otherwise outer character
                            Implicitly print


Python 3, 168 bytes
x=''
c=0
s='allworkandnoplaymakesjackadullboy'
for i in input():x+=i if not i.isalpha()else s[c%33]if i.islower()else s[c%33].upper();c+=1 if i.isalpha()else 0
print(x)

more readable:
x=''
c=0
s='allworkandnoplaymakesjackadullboy'
for i in input():
  x+=i if not i.isalpha()else s[c%33]if i.islower()else s[c%33].upper()
  c+=1if i.isalpha()else 0
print(x)

explanation: (scroll to the right)
x=''
c=0
s='allworkandnoplaymakesjackadullboy'
for i in input():
  x+=i if not i.isalpha()else s[c%33]if i.islower()else s[c%33].upper()
  c+=1if i.isalpha()else 0
print(x)­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁣⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁤⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁢⁣⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁣⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁣⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁣⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­

x=''                                                                     # ‎⁡init solution variable
c=0                                                                      # ‎⁢init counter
s='allworkandnoplaymakesjackadullboy'                                    # ‎⁣the string to convert into
for i in input():                                                        # ‎⁤loop around input
  x+=i                                                                   # ‎⁢⁡add current char to x as is
       if not i.isalpha()                                                # ‎⁢⁢if the current character is not a letter
                         else s[c%33]                                    # ‎⁢⁣otherwise add the c'th value of the string to x
                                     if i.islower()                      # ‎⁢⁤if the current character is lowercase
                                                   else s[c%33].upper()  # ‎⁣⁡or add the uppercase c'th value of the string to x (only other case)
  c+=1if i.isalpha()else 0                                               # ‎⁣⁢if the current character is a letter, increment c
print(x)                                                                 # ‎⁣⁣output x


Created with the help of Luminespire.
(noob solution, hopefully it's not that bad)

Raku (Perl 6) (rakudo), 142 bytes
my @c='allworkandnoplaymakesjackadullboy'.comb;my @s=@*ARGS.comb;
@s.=map({$_~~/\w/??($_ eq .uc??@c.shift.uc!!@c.shift.lc)!!$_});
say @s.join;

my @c='allworkandnoplaymakesjackadullboy'.comb; # split into array
my @s=@*ARGS.comb;                              # input into array
@s.=map({           # for each element                 
$_~~/\w/            # if it's a alpha character
??($_ eq .uc        # if uppercase
??@c.shift.uc       # pop character and uppercase
!!@c.shift.lc)      # pop character and lowercase
!!$_});             # if not alpha, copy char
say @s.join;        # prettier print


Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 229 bytes
f[i_]:=(w=i~StringCases~LetterCharacter;j=1;StringJoin[If[LetterQ[#],#/.Thread[w->MapThread[If[#2,ToUpperCase@#,#]&,{Characters@StringTake["allworkandnoplaymakesjackadullboy",Length@w],UpperCaseQ/@w}]][[j++]],#]&/@Characters@i]);

Try it online!

JavaScript (Node.js), 100 bytes
x=>x.replace(/[a-z]/gi,c=>c<{t:t='allworkandnoplaymakesjackadullboy'[i++%33]}?t.toUpperCase():t,i=0)

Try it online!

sed -r, 135 bytes
Needs to be run with LC_COLLATE=C to make sure that the range expression [A-Z] actually means "uppercase letters".
The script of 135 bytes (TIO link) is pure ASCII, and contains four different non-printable control characters; these are visually represented by Ø, ø, ¦, and ™ in the listing below (the latter being encoding-dependent, and possibly longer than one byte).
s/[A-Z]/Ø/g
s/[a-z]/ø/g
:1
/¦y/!s/$/¦yoblludakcajsekamyalpondnakrowlla/
s/(Ø|ø)(.+)(.)$/\1™\3\2/
s/Ø™(.)/\u\1/
s/ø™(.)/\l\1/
t1
s/¦.*//
Try it online! (Wrapped in bash to force the C locale)
